# Are dependencies supposed to be packaged with a maven jar artifact?

Tags: maven, dep

Sonatype's *Maven:The Complete Reference* says that a compile scoped dependency is on all classpaths and is packaged with the artifact.

> Compile is the default scope; all dependencies are compile-scoped if a
>   scope is not supplied. compile dependencies are available in all
>   classpaths, and they are packaged.

I can't see that they are packaged though . . . doesn't this mean that they should be contained in the jar file?  If not, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Compiled scope dependencies does not get packaged with the output jar. (with JAR plugin). I think the 'package' refers to the end product (binary executable).

I came across this stackOverflow thread ([How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)). Here they are packaging all the dependencies to build a executable out of Main class. In that case you need all the compile time dependencies in your packaged executable. (since JAVA lazy loads it is not a must, but preferable to have all the compile time dependencies)

Comment: I don't think that the 'package' refers to the end product executable as you describe it.  I say this because the "provided" scope, as discussed in the same book, is described as a scope where the dependencies are not packaged into the WAR artifact.  The WAR and JAR are both produced during the package phase . . . perhaps the answer is that a Jar package never puts the dependencies in the artifact.  This would lead me to conclude that for a JAR's there is NO difference between compile and provided scope . . . how do you feel about that statement ;)

Comment: I think your argument is a valid one. Provided scope only makes sense when the packaging type is war (there can be other packaging types too).